# Understanding thread.join(timeout)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

So **the *timeout* param, for a thread, should stop the thread after *timeout* seconds** (if it hasn't terminated yet).

In my software I'm trying to replace a *Queue.Queue.join()* (it contains an item for every thread: each thread will run Queue.Queue.task_done()) that could stop the software if a thread doesn't terminate. So if a thread, among other 50, doesn't terminate then it is all freezed.

**I want that every thread stops in 5 seconds**, for example. So i will start each thread with timeout of 5 seconds. Is it correct?

**CODE**

```
import threading
import time

def tt(name, num):
    while True:
        num += 0.5
        print 'thread ' + str(name) + ' at time ' + str(num)
        time.sleep(0.5)


for i in range(3):
    t=threading.Thread(target=tt, args=(i, 0))
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
    t.join(timeout=1)

print 'end'
```

**RESULT**

It is not properly working.. every thread should stop after 1 second. Thread 0 stops after 3 secs, thread 1 after 2 secs.

```
thread 0 at time 0.5
thread 0 at time 1.0
thread 1 at time 0.5
thread 0 at time 1.5
thread 0 at time 2.0
thread 1 at time 1.0
thread 2 at time 0.5
thread 0 at time 2.5
thread 1 at time 1.5
thread 2 at time 1.0thread 1 at time 2.0

thread 0 at time 3.0
end
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what `timeout` does. It just tells `join` how long to wait for the thread to stop. If the thread is still running after the timeout expires, the `join` call ends, but the thread keeps running.

From the docs:

> > When the timeout argument is present and not None,
> >     it should be a floating point number specifying a   timeout for the operation in seconds (or fractions thereof). As join() always returns None, you must call isAlive() after join() to decide whether a timeout happened – if the thread is still alive, the join() call timed out.

Comment: ok.. so if i started 3 threads they wouldn't stop. But they stopped.. why?

Comment: @Jimmy5nomama they're being ended when your main thread ends, because you used `setDaemon(True) `.

Comment: but if i set them as Daemons, they should go on on their own, while the main can go ahead by its own (without the join()). Correct me if it is wrong, please

Comment: @Jimmy5nomama the `daemon` flag tells Python that the thread shouldn't keep the program alive if the main thread is complete. If `daemon` is False, the program will stay alive until the thread is complete, even if the main thread is finished.

Comment: Thank you very much, one last thing.. do you know how could i do to start threads that stop within *timeout* seconds? Should i use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14924210/1647254?