# Python join with timeout = 0

Tags: python, multithreading, join, timeout

I am working on a code I haven't written myself.

I found the following line of code:
`thread.join(timeout=0.0)` applied on a `threading.Thread` object.

What could be the purpose of such a line?

EDIT: my question specifically refers to the `timeout=0`. Is there any purpose in using a `join` with a `timeout=0`? It is my understanding that a `join` purpose it to wait, therefore using a `timeout=0` seems a little contradictory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding thread.join(timeout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855335/understanding-thread-jointimeout)

Answer (score 0):

Timeout basically means the time when the `join` thread will end. Therefore, a thread.join(timeout=0.0) will end in 0 seconds. However, a thread.join(timeout=1.0) will run for one second, before closing. Now, if the thread is still running after the timeout expires, the join call ends, but the thread keeps running.

As for `.join()` it is what causes the main thread to wait for your thread to finish. Otherwise, your thread runs all by itself.

So one way to think of .`join()` as a "hold" on the main thread -- it sort of de-threads your thread and executes sequentially in the main thread, before the main thread can continue. It assures that your thread is complete before the main thread moves forward. Note that this means it's ok if your thread is already finished before you call the `.join()` -- the main thread is simply released immediately when `.join()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

The `threading` documentation explains it well:

> When the `timeout` argument is present and not `None`, it should be a floating point number specifying a timeout for the operation in seconds (or fractions thereof). As `join()` always returns `None`, you must call `is_alive()` after `join()` to decide whether a timeout happened – if the thread is still alive, the `join()` call timed out.

In essence, the `timeout` argument tells `join()` how long to wait for the thread to finish. If the length of time dictated by `timeout` expires, the `join()` call will end, but the thread will continue running. That is why you would need to call `is_alive()` to check if the thread is still running.

Setting the `timeout` argument to `0.0` would wait 0.0 seconds before timing out, thus, it would time out immediately. So to answer your question, no, there really would be no purpose for calling `join()` and passing `0.0`, as there would be no wait.